# Redefine a symbol

Tags: article-writing

I am writing a paper and I wish to redefine a symbol (in this case the $\Rightarrow$ symbol in latex) to read that if $X\Rightarrow Y$ then $X$ "uses" $Y$, where "uses" has meaning in the context of the problem. Is it enough to state this that I am redefining this? Is this allowed? Is there another symbol I should use?

Comment: You might consider using `prec` or `preceq` for unusual orders.  (displays as $\prec$ and $\preceq$ respectively)

Comment: I don't have a particular replacement symbol to choose, but in my opinion, the double arrow doesn't seem particularly apt.  Whatever symbol you choose (so long as the application isn't too jarring), I think it should be sufficient for you to clearly set out what it means.

Comment: In my experience, people wouldn't appreciate a common symbol like that being redefined.

Comment: $X \cup Y$ (just kidding)

Comment: How about $\rightarrowtail$? Is this a better symbol to redefine?